# XSL FO Match On First Child Node With Specific Attribute Value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have an FO stylesheet where I want to match on the first occurrence of a particular node with a particular attribute value.  In the example below, I want to match on the first `<dataSet>` node where the name attribute equals 'MYNAME'.

```
<xsl:template match="dataSet[@name='MYNAME'][1]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
<dataSet name='ALERTS'>
...
</dataSet>
<dataSet name='MYNAME'>
...
</dataSet>
<dataSet name='MYNAME'>
...
</dataset>
```

The above template match does not work.  What is the proper way to get the desired node?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - see: [mcve].

Comment: The `xsl:apply-templates` that selects the `dataSet` is just as important as the template that processes the `dataSet`.  `match="dataSet[@name='MYNAME'][1]"` will match on the first `dataSet` in the current context.  Is the `xsl:apply-templates` selecting all of the `dataSet` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want match first dataSet[@name='MYNAME'] within parent element and you can use XSLT 2.0, following template will work.

```
<xsl:template match="dataSet[. is (parent::*/dataSet[string(@name) eq 'MYNAME'])[1]]">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you want match first dataSet[@name='MYNAME'] within document, follwoing template will work.

```
<xsl:variable name="firstDataSet" as="element()?" select="(//dataSet[string(@name)  eq 'MYNAME'])[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="dataSet[. is $firstDataSet]">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

These templates does not depend on how dataSet template is applied from upper structure.

For your reference I added the equivalent XSLT 1.0 stylesheet corresponds to  above example.

```
<xsl:template match="dataSet[@name='MYNAME'][generate-id(.) = generate-id((parent::*/dataSet[string(@name) = 'MYNAME'])[1])]">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Or

```
<xsl:template match="dataSet[@name='MYNAME'][generate-id(.) = generate-id((//dataSet[string(@name) = 'MYNAME'])[1])]">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```